# What forces act on a caravan being towed by a car?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, friction

What forces act on a caravan that is being towed by a car?

How does this compare to a simple car travelling at a constant speed?

Comment: That's a fairly broad question. Can you be more explicit about what you are looking for? There are the obvious force of the tow hitch, rolling friction, upward force of road, and air drag; but I suspect that you have something else in mind?

Comment: On a straight road with constant speed, the only additional forces are that of air resistance. But I suspect you are asking for more that this. So please add more details because at this point the question is too broad.